# Run docker daemon with lower 1gb ram

Tags: docker

My VPS has only 1gb RAM. Does any way to make Docker daemon run with 512 MB setting (The lowser of setting tab of Docker Daemon program is 1GB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although its not a good idea to use only 512 MB ram to run docker still if you want to use docker with that much ram you can make swap space here is the guide which would help you to achieve the same

[how to make swap space in ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: i will try this

Comment: it will work for sure if you face any issue let me know

Comment: it don't tell anything about docker :(

Comment: its not related to docker swap space use your hardisk as a ram also known as virtual memory so just follow the guide and then try to install docker

Comment: My VPS is Windows 10, could you tell me something to made it ?

Comment: Is it Virtual memory in windows 10 ?

Comment: https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx

Comment: I done this. But docker daemon not run, it still say "out of memory"

Comment: see because you are using windows vps and on windows docker create another virtual machine so it depends whether your host provides you with nested virtualization or not

Comment: is it compulsory to use windows vps ?

Comment: I found a solution. By download docker.exe & dockerd.exe, then install it as windows services. And it done !!!